# How to use Model in function parameter to reduce code in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

This is how i am trying to update record in my laravel function which doesn't work

```
  public function completePacking(SaleOrder $saleOrder)
  {
    $saleOrder->update(['status' => 'Draft']);
  }
```

it is working

```
  public function completePacking($id)
  {
     $saleOrder = SaleOrder::findOrFail($id);
     $saleOrder->status = 'Dispatched';
     $saleOrder->save();
}
```

i want to use first method because it is less code but that is not working

Answer (score 1):

Add 'status' to your  $fillable attribute in your SaleOrder model.

Or remove 'status' from $guarded attribute in SaleOrder model.

After doing any of the following, you would be able to use your desired version to update status.

Read more on https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#mass-assignment

Answer (score 0):

```
$saleOrder = SaleOrder::where('id', $id)->update(['status' => 'Draft']);
```

Comment: a verbal explanation is often helpful

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply. [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25737342)